Upcoming research on Stack Overflow and across the SE network (Aug 2024)
Today, I shared an update on the blog about the research we will be conducting over the next quarter.
TL;DR – this quarter’s research focus is as follows:

Motivation, incentives, and gamification
Improving the answering
experience

This type of research typically operates months in advance and can sometimes result in us making the decision that there is not a problem we are well-positioned to solve at this time.
We will also be performing tactical research around the new asker experience in Staging Ground and activation/homepage throughout the quarter. Again, I implore you to sign up for research invitations in your account settings. We need community members like you, who are highly engaged in giving feedback on Meta, to participate in our research to engage in deep conversations around key areas of interest. If you are interested in helping us learn—sign up!

just wanted to point out that I went thru the chain of linked articles but I could not find what the "five motivation areas" are. You could probably get more participation if you disclosed some details about that so that people can see if they are interested in the research.

Has your research involving human subjects been through an IRB? Slightly, but not completely, tongue in cheek.

we crafted hypotheses in the form of Jobs-to-be-Done ... 4/5 Jobs-to-be-Done - are those 4 of the 5 hypotheses? As mentioned in our last blog post, one of our researchers hypothesized five motivation groups through a cluster analysis ...and more. Over the next quarter or two, we hope to validate these hypotheses motivation area == hypothesis?

Apologies @QHarr I was on vacation. We are hoping to release the motivation groups in a research blog post in the future. Those motivation groups are created with research, but the Jobs-to-be-Done which take the motivations further by adding context around why someone may use SO/SE and what their biggest problems are have not been validated. We also don't know how many of our users fall into each motivation group, which makes prioritization hard!
